# Best practice for using caching the results of an iterator block

Tags: c#, linq

Iterator blocks' lazy loading behavior is causing difficulties in caching data. Consider this small test program:

```
class Program
{
    static IEnumerable<int> LoadDataFromDatabase()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hitting database....");
        yield return 13;
    }

    static IEnumerable<int> _cachedData = null;
    static IEnumerable<int> CachedData
    {
        get
        {
            if (_cachedData == null)
            {
                _cachedData = LoadDataFromDatabase();
            }
            return _cachedData;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Collection contains {0} items.", CachedData.Count()));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Collection contains {0} items.", CachedData.Count()));
    }
}
```

The output to this is

> Hitting database....
>
> Collection contains 1 items.
>
> Hitting database....
>
> Collection contains 1 items.

I want to only hit the database once (hence the caching), but because `LoadDataFromDatabase()` is an iterator block, the actual database call is what's cached -- not the data.

What is the best practice in this scenario? Should I just do `_cachedData = LoadDataFromDatabase().ToList()` to store the evaluated data?

Comment: How much data do you expect `LoadDataFromDatabase` to load, and will it ever need to change over the lifetime of your application?  If the answers are a little and no change, then for simplicity you should probably just store the data as a list.

Comment: I can assume that if I am caching the data, I do need the entire list so it's always OK to evaluate the entire data set. And I do have a mechanism in place for dirtying the data. I am wondering if `.ToList()` is a standard way to work around the lazy evaluation, or if there's something more recommended (for example is there some attribute I can put on the iterator block method to tell C# to not lazy-evaluate).

Comment: you want to cache smth not to hit database twice - correct?

Comment: I don't know what the "best practice" is for this situation, but calling `ToList` should work just fine.  As for the lazy evaluation, the compiler just builds a state machine out of the logic you write into the iterator block.  In this case, "eager" evaluation would be precisely storing the data in a list.  So either call `ToList` on the iterator block's result, or just modify your `LoadFromDataBase` method to fill a list, rather than yield an enumeration.

Comment: i would suggest converting to List and cache the list.

Answer (score 3):

You could add `.ToList()`:

```
static IEnumerable<int> CachedData
{
    get
    {
        if (_cachedData == null)
        {
            _cachedData = LoadDataFromDatabase().ToList();
        }
        return _cachedData;
    }
}
```

The disadvantage is that if there a 100.000 items in the list and you do this:

```
var list1 = CachedData.Take(2).Sum();
var list2 = CachedData.Take(3).Sum();
var list3 = CachedData.Take(1).Sum();
```

... it will load 100.000 items of the list.

The solution is to make implement a `LazyList` that caches the Enumerable **while** you are iterating and not in advance. Just replace `.ToList()` with `.ToLazyList()`.

This results in the best option:

- The first 3 items are only loaded 1 time in total.
- Item 4 has never been loaded

An example of an [implementation of a lazy list is here](http://www.siepman.nl/blog/post/2013/10/09/LazyList-A-better-LINQ-result-cache-than-List.aspx).

Comment: I think you should keep it simple, as you do in the first part of the answer. He should only consider alternative solutions if there is problem with performance.

Comment: KISS is a principle that I like very much and it does not happen very often that the same iterator is used in 2 nested for each loops. That are good reasons for the first simple solution. However, it is not correct in some cases so I made a more complex version that works correct in all (single threaded) situations. You can choose your owm implementation.